# On Scroll, RecyclerView values getting empty and some changing to old values

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

**I have created OrderItemRecyclerAdapter. After entering the values in Editetext and when I scroll it then values are getting empty means it is getting replace to first values.**

**I have pasted my total adapter code. I'm unable to to find the error. Can anyone solve it.**

```
public class OrderItemRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OrderItemRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    TextView orderAmountTxt, orderItemsTxt;
    Context myContext;
    ArrayList<ItemsGetterSetter> itemArrayList;
    ArrayList<Integer> itemAmountArray;
    ArrayList<Boolean> itemAvailableArray;
    TextView orderSaveTxtBtn;

    public OrderItemRecyclerAdapter(TextView orderAmountTxt, TextView orderItemsTxt, Context myContext, ArrayList<ItemsGetterSetter> itemArrayList, ArrayList<Integer> itemAmountArray, ArrayList<Boolean> itemAvailableArray, TextView orderSaveTxtBtn) {
        this.orderAmountTxt = orderAmountTxt;
        this.orderItemsTxt = orderItemsTxt;
        this.myContext = myContext;
        this.itemArrayList = itemArrayList;
        this.itemAmountArray = itemAmountArray;
        this.itemAvailableArray = itemAvailableArray;
        this.orderSaveTxtBtn = orderSaveTxtBtn;
    }



    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(myContext).inflate(R.layout.itemview_list, parent, false);
        final OrderItemRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder vHolder = new ViewHolder(view);


        return vHolder;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
        itemAvailableArray.add(position, itemArrayList.get(position).isItemAvailable());
        itemAmountArray.add(position, itemArrayList.get(position).getAmount());
        holder.itemNameTxt.setText(itemArrayList.get(position).getItemName());
        holder.isAvailableSwitch.setChecked(itemArrayList.get(position).isItemAvailable());
        holder.itemAmountEditTxt.setText(String.valueOf(itemArrayList.get(position).getAmount()));

    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView itemNameTxt;
        EditText itemAmountEditTxt;
        Switch isAvailableSwitch;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemNameTxt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemNameTxt);
            itemAmountEditTxt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemAmountEditTxt);
            isAvailableSwitch = itemView.findViewById(R.id.isAvailableSwitch);
        }
    }
}
```

**Kindly look into this code.**

Answer (score -1):

try using holder.getAdapterPosition to get the position

```
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
            ItemsGetterSetter item = itemArrayList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition())
    
            itemAvailableArray.add(holder.getAdapterPosition(), item.isItemAvailable());
            itemAmountArray.add(holder.getAdapterPosition(), item.getAmount());
            holder.itemNameTxt.setText(item.getItemName());
            holder.isAvailableSwitch.setChecked(item.isItemAvailable());
            holder.itemAmountEditTxt.setText(String.valueOf(item.getAmount()));
    
        }
```

Comment: after modification the code as per you suggestion, still starting values are reflecting when i scroll the view.